# postmaster.pid & pg_hba.conf

Tags: postgresql

I’m installing a postgresql 10 server ...after configure postgresql.conf file to accept all ip addreses & port 5432 ..i can run the server and create tables…
when I configure the pg_hba.conf file though:

```
   host    my_db   +user_group  0.0.0.0/0   scram-sha-256
```

and start the server again:

```
   user@server-name:~$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl  -D 
                     /usr/local/pgsql/data -l logfile start
   server starting
   user@server-name:~$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql  postgres
   psql: could not connect to server : No such file or directory.
           Is the server running locally and accepting connections
          on Unix domain socket “/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432”?
```

the server stops & I noticed that the postmaster.pid file at the data directory disappear …
when I remove the configurations from the pg_hba.conf file , the server works and postmaster.pid reappears again !!
I checked many questions..but couldn't find a case like mine..

deleting the postmaster.pid is not recommended ..I'm using Ubuntu Server 18

any idea why this happens ?

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log file. That will tell you.

Comment: @Laurenzon Albe : strange why the authentication not accept scram-sha-256 when i normally use it ?!

Comment: @Laurenzo  Albe ..the scram-sha-256 authentication shutting down the database service !! I usually use it with no issues ...and Postgresql recommend it over the md5 .

Comment: LOG:  invalid authentication method "scram-sha-256"
CONTEXT:  line 87 of configuration file "/usr/local/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf"
FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf
LOG:  database system is shut down

Comment: I just tried the md5 ..and faced no issues ..For some reason the service doesn't accept the scram-sha-256 this time.

Comment: Simple. You must have made a mistake, and it is a PostgreSQL version older than v10.

Comment: @Lorenzon Albe  ..Actually it's a customized Postgresql with version 9.6 I believe ..I installed from source code ..to be able to apply the Data-at-rest encryption...still its from postgresql.. So yes what you said might be the reason . Thank you.

Comment: You said PostgreSQL 10 in your question... I'll close the question then.

Comment: @ Lorenzo Albe... Oh yes I just noticed.. I shouldn't add the version 10..my mistake.